# How to filter a Django model by properties of a reverse foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I need to filter a Django model based on properties of a reverse foreign key and I'm not sure of the best way to do this.

I have two models in which `Products` belong to a `ProductRange`

```
class ProductRange(models.Model):
   pass

class Product(models.Model):
   product_range = models.ForeignKey(ProductRange, related_name="products")
   is_archived = models.BooleanField()
```

Product Ranges in which all products are set `is_archived=True` are to be considered archived, if any products are not marked as archived they are not considered archived.

I need a way to filter Product Ranges based on this, i.e a filter that returns product ranges for which **all** products are archived.

I'm aware I can filter by the related name:

```
ProductRange.objects.filter(products__is_archived=False)
```

However this returns product ranges where **Any** product is archived no **all** products.

I'm also aware I can do the filtering in Python but I need this filter work on a large dataset and I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this in the database.

I've also considered using `models.Subquery` or `models.Exists`, however I feel like there is probably a simpler and more performant way of doing this that I am missing, also this would require a lot of refactoring to avoid a circular import.

I feel like I'm missing a very simple solution here if anyone knows what it is?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to annotate the queryset with a filtered count of the related field and then filter by the annotation.

```
ProductRange.objects.annotate(
   active_product_count=models.Count(
        "products",
        filter=models.Q(products__is_archived=False),
        distinct=True)
    ).filter(active_product_count__gte=1)
```

I'm still not sure this is the best solution but it works.